# Problem programming Mini Pro via Arduino as ISP

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, avrdude, isp, clones, arduinoisp

I just picked up a pair of Arduino Mini Pro 5v clone boards (Inland, sold at Microcenter, currently $4 USD) and I wanted to use my Uno as an ISP like I've done with ATmega328 and ATtiny85 chips before.  I've programmed the Uno with the instructions at [the ArduinoISP tutorial page](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) and I've connected up the Uno to the Mini Pro using the instructions at [this page](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/MiniBootloader).  I cannot get the Arduino IDE or avrdude from the command line to successfully program these boards no matter what I try.  Except that I can use the Arduino IDE to burn a new bootloader to the Mini Pro.

I've connected up the status LEDs as well (pins 7, 8 and 9), and I can see that the programmer has an error condition (pin 8) when I attempt to program anything besides the bootloader.

Here is my avrdude command line where I tried to set the fuses on the Mini Pro:

```
avrdude -P /dev/tty.usbmodema0121 -b 57600 -c avrisp -p atmega328p -U lfuse:w:0xff:m -U hfuse:w:0xdb:m -U efuse:w:0xfd:m
```

I get the following back from avrdude:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I've not had any problems with using pretty much this exact same setup, but with a ATmega328 or ATtiny85 chip on a breadboard with avrdude in the past, so I'm at a loss as to what is happening here.

I've also taken a look at the ArduinoISP code, and I'm not really sure what the resp=0x1c is.  I don't see a 0x1c value defined in the STK Definitions section of the code, so I'm not sure what might be causing this.

Any pointers here would be appreciated. And yes, I do know that I can use the Uno board with the ATmega328 chip pulled to use as a programmer as well.  But I want to be able to overwrite the bootloader area with my own code like I can with a regular ATmega328 chip.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After poking around for a bit more, it turns out my problem was the baud rate.  I could make it work by setting it to 19200, just a little slower.  Alternatively, you can modify the ArduinoISP sketch to enable higher baud rates.  I used [this post](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=48784.5) to enable 115200 baud and I was able to successfully use avrdude at the higher rates.

Not sure how I missed this before, but it's an easy to solve at least.